# Using Mongo Spark connector to insert dataframe using the overwrite mode

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

The overwrite mode using the following statement:
DataFrameWriter dfw = df2.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite);

And then:
MongoSpark.save(dfw);

I see the collection being dropped, but is not re-created.  From what I understand the "overwrite" mode is supposed to recreate collections.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to double check `df2` contains some actual data?

Comment: Thanks Ross. Data exists. I got it working when I persisted the rdd to memory prior to save.